# Is it possible to automatically update rule analytics on Sentinel?

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

The Microsoft analytics rule templates get updates from time to time to include additional constraints within their KQL. Currently I'm manually updating each of the rule templates that have been updated by Microsoft.

I was wondering if it is possible to somehow automate this process to avoid having to update each rule manually?